# Making a Team Build Workflow wait for an external event/input

Tags: tfsbuild

Our build workflows are a bit involved in the sense they sometimes have to wait on the availability of some shared resources before they can progress.

Is there a way to sort of create a "bookmark" in a build workflow and have it wait until the resource in question is available? I would hate to have to code the workflow in a way that it merely sits and executes a look every 10 seconds or so waiting for the shared resource to be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the way to do this is just as you suggest and take a "polling" approach where the workflow loops and just keeps checking on the shared resource, then waits a while and checks again.

If you look in the [ALM Ranger Build Guidance](http://vsarbuildguide.codeplex.com/) they have an example of doing exactly that on Page 86 where they want the build to pause and wait for manual input (in that case they loops and keep checking for the existence of a "semaphore file").

Comment: You are quite right on that. In the same guide however they have also mentioned on Page 101 that you can use NativeActivity and leverage the complete power of bookmarks etc. I am keen to explore a better way of achieving this other than using the polling mechanism. As I mentioned our build workflows are quite extensive (the shared resrouce bit is just an example). Ideally I want to persist the WF and offload it until an external stimulus kicks it back into action again.